# How to use mongodb $group in java?

Tags: java, json, mongodb, group-by, mongodb-java

I have a collection processedClickLog in MongoDB.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ffb4cefbe21fa7896e2d73"),
        "ID" : "81a5d7f48e5df09c9bc006e7cc89d6e6",
        "USERID" : "206337611536",
        "DATETIME" : "Fri Mar 31 17:29:34 -0400 2017",
        "QUERYTEXT" : "Tom",
        "DOCID" : "www.demo.com",
        "TITLE" : "Harry Potter",
        "TAB" : "People-Tab",
        "TOTALRESULTS" : "1",
        "DOCRANK" : 1
}
{      "id":
        ....
}
```

I am trying to execute a complex query in java. My query is to get processedClickLog collection where

1. TAB is not equal to People-Tab
2. DOCRANK is not equal to 0
3. only return "USERID", "DOCID", "DOCRANK", "QUERYTEXT" fields
4. Group by USERID

Below is my Java code. I am able to satisfy the first three condition. But I am stuck on 4th condition which is group by USERID.

```
String jsonResult = "";
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test1");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("processedClickLog");
        //add condition where TAB is not equal to "People-Tab" and DOCRANK is not equal to 0
        List<DBObject> criteria = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
        criteria.add(new BasicDBObject("DOCRANK", new BasicDBObject("$ne", 0)));
        criteria.add(new BasicDBObject("TAB", new BasicDBObject("$ne", "People-Tab")));

            //combine the above two conditions
            BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$and", criteria);
            //to retrieve all the documents with specific fields 
            MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query)
                    .projection(Projections.include("USERID", "DOCID", "DOCRANK", "QUERYTEXT")).iterator();
      try {
                while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println(cursor.next().toJson());

                }
            } finally {
                cursor.close();
            }
            System.out.println(hashMap);
            mongoClient.close();
    }
```

How should I define my whole query to add the condition "group by USERID" in java? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've to use aggregation framework. Statically import all the methods of helper classes and use the below code.

Use of `BasicDBObject` is not required in newer 3.x driver api. You should use the new class `Document` for similar needs.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Projections.*;

Bson match = match(and(ne("DOCRANK", 0), ne("TAB", "People-Tab")));
Bson group = group("$USERID", first("USERID", "$USERID"), first("DOCID", "$DOCID"), first("DOCRANK", "$DOCRANK"), first("QUERYTEXT", "$QUERYTEXT"));
Bson projection = project(fields(include("USERID", "DOCID", "DOCRANK", "QUERYTEXT"), excludeId()));
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.aggregate(asList(match, group, projection)).iterator();
```

Projection stage is optional, only added to give a complete example.

More about aggregation here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain in brief about the group part? I didn't find anything related to that in the reference link.

Comment: You are welcome. Its same as [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) concept in sql. You group by a key and run [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) to collect the data. For more on how to use group with java driver go here  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.1/builders/aggregation/#group