# How to make Group By statement using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I recover from the two cursor database:
the first containing weather information with a date greater than January 5, 2018.
the second retrieves traffic data with a date greater than January 5, 2018
I want to match the two cursors to do an analysis according to the date axis so I wanted to do the query group by fields date

```
DBCollection c = dataBase.getCollection("InfoClimatData");
    DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("Date").greaterThanEquals("05/01/2018").get();
    DBCursor d = c.find(query);
    while (d.hasNext()){
       System.out.println(d.next().get("Date"));

    }
    DBCollection cTrafic = dataBase.getCollection("TraficData");
    DBObject queryTrafic =   QueryBuilder.start("horodate").greaterThanEquals("05/01/2018").get();
    DBCursor dTrafic = cTrafic.find(queryTrafic);
    while (dTrafic.hasNext()){
     System.out.println(dTrafic.next().get("Date"));

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use mongodb $group in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43646407/how-to-use-mongodb-group-in-java)

Comment: it's not a duplication i'm talking on another context